# ERROR: Error installing ffi: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

Got the DevKit installed and re-ran the ffi install….got this as an output:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\******>gem install ffi
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()... yes
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile
make
C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_ffi_c'"  > ffi_c-i386-mingw32.def
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1
.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extcon
f.h\"    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -
Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-declaration-a
fter-statement   -o AbstractMemory.o -c AbstractMemory.c
In file included from AbstractMemory.c:28:0:
compat.h:65:20: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
compat.h:69:24: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive
In file included from AbstractMemory.h:29:0,
                 from AbstractMemory.c:29:
Types.h:68:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [AbstractMemory.o] Error 1 

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.1
0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.10/ext/ffi_c/gem_m
ake.out
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

Not sure how to deal with this issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 23):

The gem install ffi fails due to the gem trying to build a bundled copy of libffi, which does not work due to assumptions that /usr/bin/env exists and too old libffi copy.

However, you can build the ffi gem against the system libffi - install the packages:

```
apt install clang make ruby-dev libffi-dev
```

After that the ffi gem should build:

```
gem install ffi
```

Comment: What about macos?

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

This worked for me

Comment: This is what worked for me, as well, on a Linux Mint system.  Here's a hint to future seekers (for what it's worth to posterity): a gem that won't automatically install generally requires, in my experience, the system's own package manager to install the 'dev' version of a related package.

Answer (score 16):

Version 1.0.10 has issues compiling on windows.

You can use the 1.0.9

```
gem install ffi --version='1.0.9'
```

Comment: +1 thank you so much, this helped me install middleman on my Win7 box

Comment: `ERROR:  Error installing railties:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Comment: Is the error happening with the same ruby and ffi version which Windows OS?

Answer (score 8):

For me the fix was running in this order. I'm not sure what all was relevant, but it worked:

```
gem install ffi --version '1.0.9'
```

The above failed, but then I could successfully run:

```
gem install bundler
```

...and subsequently:

```
gem install ffi
```

...which got the latest version (1.6.0 at the time of writing this) and installed it successfully.

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 7):

when the above steps are followed, it might results the following message.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
You have requested:
ffi = 1.0.9

The bundle currently has ffi locked at 1.0.11.
Try running `bundle update ffi`
```

In that case, you can run the 'bundle update ffi' command and the error will be solved.

Comment: `bundle update ffi` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Note that installing version 1.0.9 isn't going to be enough if your bundler keeps trying to go out and grab the latest version. In your gemfile you'll also want to put:

```
gem 'ffi', '1.0.9'
```

This should satisfy the dependency for whatever gem is asking for it and let you get up and running.

Answer (score 4):

Installing the 'osx-gcc-installer' worked for me: (osx 10.8)

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

Comment: the environment used for the question is windows

Comment: Newer versions of macOS may simply `xcode-select --install` to get the compilers.

Comment: This link is not working

Answer (score 4):

Helped me:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Debian 9

Ruby 2.3.3

Answer (score 4):

For me, this usually works

```
gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi
```

Comment: This works when installing the gem by itself, but not if `ffi` is being installed by `bundle install`.

Answer (score 3):

you need this,

```
apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Copied from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938533/running-into-errors-installing-ffi-gem-on-os-x-mountain-lion/15684432#15684432):

As stated in [Issue with installing ImageMagick and rmagick on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676844/issue-with-installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick-on-mountain-lion), ffi appears to be configured to look for 'gcc-4.2', so once I updated my [Apple command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=Command%20Line%20Tools%20%28OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion%29#) (which I may or may not have needed to do), I created a symbolic link to make the ffi install configuration happy:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly after I installed the Apple CLI tools.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
`gem install ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`
*on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL)*

Comment: This works when installing the gem by itself, but not if `ffi` is being installed by `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS (Catalina), running `brew install libtool` first solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put DevKit in front of your PATH, and install again from Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case, I have not install the DevKit, which can be found: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. After installing DevKit, just follow the instruction https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit and finally it's up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `automake` to get it working. Worked on both mac OSX as well as Ubuntu (CI machine).

Answer (score 0):

Run this: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Then: brew install cocoapods

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).