# Issue with installing ImageMagick and rmagick on Mountain Lion

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick, osx-mountain-lion

I am facing issues with installing rmagick in mountain lion. I have installed Xcode 4.4 and developer tools. Still facing this issue.

```
    Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
    /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

            /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for clang... yes
    checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
    checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
    /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:530:in `block in build_extensions'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `each'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `build_extensions'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:90:in `block in install'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:82:in `preserve_paths'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:89:in `install'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:73:in `block in install_gem_from_spec'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:97:in `with_build_args'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `install_gem_from_spec'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:56:in `block in run'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /Users/mohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just updated to Mountain Lion this morning and had rmagick troubles. I had installed ImageMagick through homebrew at some point in the past, so this worked for me after installing the new commandline tools through xcode's preferences window.

```
brew update
brew uninstall ImageMagick
brew install ImageMagick
gem uninstall rmagick
gem install rmagick
```

I didn't have to get funky with gcc like some above posts mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

I finally solved this using:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib
$ ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
$ ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
$ ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

The solution comes from https://coderwall.com/p/wnomjg

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

did it as it says in https://gist.github.com/1860511

Comment: I had this same issue with a different gem (hpricot) and this fixed it right up!

Answer (score 3):

So after updating my mac pro to Mountain Lion, my ruby environment started screaming with different errors one after another.
After 1-2 hours of trial - error and googling, here is how I fixed my ruby on rails environment.

First I got ruby env errors.It was not detecting git commands and Bundler was screaming with
errors when I ran `foreman start`

**Step1** : `Update XCode`. Get  the latest one Xcode 4.6
Mountain Lion does not come with ruby headers installed before hand, so you need to do this manually from XCode. Go to Xcode Preferences/Downloads.

`Install Command Line Tools`

**Step2:** `Install XQuartz`

Logout and Login again. (You might not need this as imagemagick formula has been updated

**Step 3:** Now your ruby env would start speaking about Imagemagick errors
Do this:

`brew update`

`brew uninstall imagemagick`

`brew install --fresh imagemagick`

`gem uninstall rmagick 2.13.2`

`gem install rmagick`

After trying the last one, now it will give you native extension errors like this

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/priyanka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... no
No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/priyanka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/priyanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-      2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/priyanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Step 4:** 
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

This should fix all issues that Mountain Lion gifted you after the upgrade.

Just run `bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your path such that /usr/local/bin is inserter before /usr/bin.   I found this running brew doctor and it allowed me to finish compiling imagemagick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick summary of how I was able to get RMagick work, after several tries. I feel the following is the best way to get it without going to the pains of downloading source tarballs and compilation - leave that to experts

- You need to have Xcode and Command Line Tools installed for gcc/g++ etc. Command line tools do not get installed automatically with Xcode, go <kbd>Preferences</kbd> and install it
- Next install [Macport](http://www.macports.org/install.php)
- Install [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) as well
- Make sure you have X11 server installed - if not install it - `sudo
  port install -v xorg-server`. I use `-v` option as it is a long install
  and you might wonder whether it is doing something or just hanging
- Install pkgconfig - `sudo brew install pkgconfig`
- now it is time to install ImageMacick - `sudo port install -v
  ImageMagick`
     *do not use brew to install ImageMagick - it does not install all the dependencies and delegates properly.*
- once ImageMagick is installed - set `DISPLAY` env variable - `export DISPLAY=:0.0` - better still put it in your `.profile`
- Now test your ImageMagick installation
- start X11 server (after X11 server installation it is will there in
  your App List)
- from command line run - `$convert logo: logo.gif; identify logo.gif; display logo.gif` - *it should pop up a window displaying `logo.gif`*
- also run a command from command line  -  `$convert -list configure | grep -i delegates`. It should output the following 
  `DELEGATES     bzlib fftw fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng lcms2 lzma png tiff x11 xml zlib`
- Now you should be set to run 
  `sudo gem install RMagick`

After RMagick is installed successfully - check where it is installed, go to examples directory within and run some of the programs.

Answer (score 1):

No solutions were working for me, eventually I ran `brew doctor` and discovered that I needed to link imagemagick with `brew link --overwrite imagemagick`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but on El Captain. Better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216030/gem-install-rmagick-fails-on-os-x-el-capitan).
Fixed after installing xcode command-line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install XCode 4.4, command line tools, etc. Check out the full listing here:
http://tektastic.com/2012/07/getting-rmagic-and-friends-to-work-on.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me was a combination of the steps listed above, at http://tektastic.com/2012/07/getting-rmagic-and-friends-to-work-on.html and here http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion, although I didn't have to do all the steps listed in either post.  But I did need to install the command line tools from XCode, I missed that detail the first few times.  I also had to install gcc-4.2 using homebrew, and make a sym link to that installation in my bin directory.

I could be confused about what's going on with the different compilers, but I would be cautious about sym linking /usr/bin/gcc to /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 (which may in turn be a link to gcc-4.2 installed by homebrew). Before I realized I needed to install the command line tools, I had tried making that sym link and then I started seeing other gem build failures. Installing the command line tools fixed those issues - I believe the xcode command line tools made it a sym link to llvm-gcc-4.2.

Comment: I also had to uninstall ImageMagick and reinstall it using Brew. Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed rmagick 2.13.2 and this issue is gone.