# An error occured while installing ffi (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ffi, osx-mountain-lion

Running OSX Mountain Lion, in a Rails 3.0 project.

When trying to update my gems with bundler in a Rails project i get the following errror:

```
An error occured while installing ffi (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.1.2'` succeeds before bundling.

ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/victorstan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

...

You have to install development tools first.
```

I have XCode installed as well as command line tools.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

See also [Issue with installing ImageMagick and rmagick on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676844/issue-with-installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick-on-mountain-lion) and https://gist.github.com/1860511.

Comment: I also needed to install the command line tools for Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=Command%20Line%20Tools%20%28OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion%29

Answer (score 6):

If you reinstall command line tools for Xcode, it should work fine. Here is the link to do so:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=Command%20Line%20Tools%20%28OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion%29