# Rails tutorial: "An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

So I'm doing [this super basic Rails tutorial][1], and I'm stuck at this part:

```
bundle install --without production
```

It runs through a list of dependencies (?) but seems to get stuck on something calling ffi 1.9.10, where it gives me the following error message:

```
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
Installing ffi 1.9.10 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/stephensmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160101-33768-1kfzc9h.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    .
    .
    .
    --without-pkg-config
/Users/stephensmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/stephensmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    .
    .
    .
    from /Users/stephensmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stephensmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@real_estate/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/stephensmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@real_estate/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
Using formatador 0.2.5
.
.
.
Using sprockets 3.5.2
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it? I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out to continue with the tutorial. :-(

Comment: did you try ```xcode-select --install```? and are you on Mavericks or Yosemite or even a mac for that matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occured while installing ffi (1.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725577/an-error-occured-while-installing-ffi-1-1-2-and-bundler-cannot-continue)

Comment: I'm on El Capitan...just did what you suggested, @MilesStanfield, and it seemed to install something, but then when I tried `bundle install --without production`, it gave me the same error.

Comment: When I try to do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` as recommended there, I get the following error:

`ln: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Stephen Smith: This doesn't address your question, but when I started learning rails I wish somebody told me about using Cloud 9 IDE for Rails development. I encountered the same issue, and unless your really need to use your machine, you can bypass all sorts of installation issues by working there in an environment designed specifically for Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your home directory is `/Users/<username>` I am guessing you are on a Mac. You need to install the Xcode command line tools as explained in this [article](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)

You can do this from the command line using `xcode-select`

Comment: All up to date, but I'm getting the same error message :-(

Comment: I get this – which is what I'm supposed to get, right? `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Yes. Can you check if the following file exists: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/ffi/ffi.h` ? You may need to change 10.9 to your version of os.

Comment: The solutions in this thread may also be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575679/bundle-update-fails-on-ffi

Comment: There is a `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/ffi/ffi.h`, yes.

Comment: So when I try to follow the instruction there, I do all of the `rm`s, but then I still get this error: `An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.` (And it goes on for a while, but you get the idea.