# gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1 error Failed to build gem native extension on Mac OS 10.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, imagick

I have tried everything by giving path of MagickWand.h, I have command tools installed. Can anyone help me out ?

```
$ gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1
```

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rmagick:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /Users/ghazanfarali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes checking for
>   /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... yes checking for Magick-config... yes checking for
>   ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes checking for HDRI disabled version
>   of ImageMagick... yes checking for stdint.h... no checking for
>   sys/types.h... no checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
>
> Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/ghazanfarali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/ruby
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/ghazanfarali/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/ghazanfarali/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
>   "

Comment: you need to install development header for imagemagick package for your os

Comment: Are you able to move to a ruby version > 1.8.7?  I am going to setup the environment and see if I experience the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I strongly suggest using something like [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh), if you are not already, to manage OSX packages.  There are alternatives, including MacPorts.

RMagic is simply a ruby interface with ruby bindings for the underlying ImageMagic package.

I would make sure the latest imagemagick is installed:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Or, if already installed:

```
brew upgrade imagemagick
```

Or, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676844/issue-with-installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick-on-mountain-lion):

```
# install latest command line tools via xcode     
# make sure you have the latest homebrew with the latest packages 
brew update
# uninstall imagemagick and then reinstall to make use updated compiler
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
# uninstall rmagick then reinstall to ensure native extensions are built against
# latest imagemagick
gem uninstall rmagick
gem install rmagick # or bundle
```

Additionally, you can run:

```
brew doctor
```

to identify any issues that may affect the building of these packages.

### Update

---

Two approaches:

1. [RMagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) was recently updated to fix build issues related to the latest ImageMagick.  Use version **2.13.2**.  Per the RMagick README:
   `This release will fix the installation issues due to ruby 1.9.3 and ImageMagick 6.8+.`
2. Probably the better approach.  Replace rmagick with [mini_magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) as mini_magick is being actively developed and rmagick is not.  Imagemagick is also in active development, so as it's API changes, RMagick's dated API will become more and more stale.

Comment: Latest imagemagick is installed  i did brew upgrade imagemagick and on brew doctor but i am facing same error still

Comment: Ok, so after digging in deeper it appears that the issue is due to an impedance mismatch between the latest imagemagick (currently updated) and rmagick (development stopped a year ago or more).  You should use the 'mini_magick' instead.

Comment: Finally I found the solution of this, special Thanks to Mr. Matt Dressel , his finding really help me resolve this issue. 

here is the link for those are facing same same issue. 

http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/

Answer (score 1):

Please check answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config). Maybe you just need:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: Anton, I agree with you.  I believe a package manager will sort out the problems he is having.

Comment: The question link you given is not helping me out. I came to ask question after trying all the related questions.