# The 'ffi' native gem requires installed build tools on windows

Tags: windows-8, rubygems

I am trying to Install guard through Ruby gem. I got the following error even when I tried to Install the previous version by referring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7903876/1577396).

```
C:\>gem install guard
Fetching: thor-0.18.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thor-0.18.1
Fetching: timers-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed timers-1.1.0
Fetching: celluloid-0.15.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed celluloid-0.15.2
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.3
Fetching: ffi-1.9.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing guard:
        The 'ffi' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'


C:\>gem install ffi --version='1.0.9'
Fetching: ffi-1.0.9.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        The 'ffi' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Answer (score 3):

get installers

1.Ruby installer

2.development kit

according to your 32 or 64 bit machine download it accordingly
you can download development kit from here [download development kit from here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

After extracting the DevKit to C:\RubyDevKit, run these these commands in cmd prompt:
C:\RubyDevKit>devkitvars.bat
Adding the DevKit to PATH...

`C:\RubyDevKit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193`

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

```
C:\RubyDevKit>ruby dk.rb install
```

[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

then install **compass** by typing in command prompt

```
"gem install compass"
```

its Done!!!