# Issue Installing ruby ffi gem dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am new to ruby on rails and I am currently following a book called "The Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl.

There is a problem with installing one of the gem dependencies and I have no idea what it could be. Here is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0146 CHAPTER 3. MOSTLY STATIC PAGES
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.3'
end
group :test do
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
#Uncomment this line on OS X.
gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
# Uncomment these lines on Linux.
# gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'
# Uncomment these lines on Windows.
# gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
# gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
*Karls-MacBook-Pro:sample_app karl$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.40
Using activesupport 4.0.5
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.5
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.5
Using activemodel 4.0.5
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.5
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.2.1
Using xpath 2.0.0
Using capybara 2.1.0
Using timers 1.1.0
Using celluloid 0.15.2
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -C (RuntimeError)
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/karl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0146 CHAPTER 3. MOSTLY STATIC PAGES/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/karl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0146 CHAPTER 3. MOSTLY STATIC PAGES/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I did try to install ffi with it's version 1.0.11 and I got this:

```
Karls-MacBook-Pro:sample_app karl$ gem install ffi -v 1.0.11
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/karl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -C (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/karl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0146 CHAPTER 3. MOSTLY STATIC PAGES/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/karl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0146 CHAPTER 3. MOSTLY STATIC PAGES/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Is this a C error of some sort? Not really sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `brew install libffi`, or to install previous version of gem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852566/error-error-installing-ffi-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)