# Failed to Install Compass 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, compass

I can't install latest Compass 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [i386-linux-gnu]

$ gem --version
2.0.14
```

I'm doing:

```
$ sudo gem install compass -v 1.0.1
```

The first error in the log is this:

```
ERROR: Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

And here's the full log:
https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/055394e379e8252bab9e

I'm installing Ruby via this packages:

```
ruby2.0
ruby2.0-dev
```

I even tried to install Ruby via RVM, but I'm getting the same error.

What could be the problem?

Is it possible to install latest version of Compass on Ubuntu 14.04 without RVM?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like problem is actually with [ffi](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) extension.

When I've tried to install `ffi` manually with this command: `sudo gem install ffi`, it failed with the same error as above. However, when I've specified latest stable version like this: `sudo gem install ffi -v 1.9.6` it installed correctly. After that Compass installed like a charm.

I will leave it here if someone will encounter this problem in the future.

Also, this Q/A could be useful:
[ERROR: Error installing ffi: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852566/error-error-installing-ffi-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

I've posted an issue on FFI's GitHub repository:
https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/414

Comment: Thanks for this. Was struggling all last night to get this working and nearly gave up. Good job I searched for answers again in the morning!