# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception) Failed to find gems ["ffi"] = 1.15.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code, rubygems

I am stuck on this and in desperate need of help! I am working in Visual Studio Code to build a Flutter app that uses Firebase. I added the following dependencies to my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
firebase_core: ^1.11.0
firebase_analytics: ^9.0.5
firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
```

My app writes a single text line to Firebase and reads it immediately afterwards(just a test app to see how things work/learn the API). I run the app on iOS Simulator and get a bunch of output in my debug console but the error at the bottom reads:

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
76

Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have run `gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0` command in the terminal and got the permissions warning. I went through the steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos) and installed Homebrew w/ `rbenv` and followed all of those steps so don't need help with that part.

I ran `brew install cocoapods`, `gem install bundler` and `gem install ffi`(recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852566/error-error-installing-ffi-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)). I've been going in circles following steps in countless different forums but the app keeps failing to launch and the debug console keeps outputting:

```
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
```

and when I run that in a terminal I keep getting:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Failed to find gems ["ffi"] = 1.15.0
```